SQL Alchemy bulk update while still handling relationships and lifecycle events (before_update, update)
I want to do a batch update of already existing objects using SQL Alchemy. I am using version 1.4.
My goal is to reduce round trips to the DB and combine update statements when possible (2 objects that have updated the same field with the same value might be combined in the same update query). I'd like to make the updates as efficient as possible.
However, I need the batch update to also handle relationships and lifecycle events, since I need to update a related normalized object for each of the objects updated in the batch update. This object is built with the notify update event listener, it does not use Joined Table Inheritance.
Is there a clean way to achieve this, either in version 1.X or 2.X?
I've explored:

batch_update_mappings: does not handle relationships nor lifecycle events. I can manually trigger the lifecycle events one by one in a loop, don't know if there is a way to update relationships manually
batch_save_objects: same as batch_update_mappings
Bulk UPDATE by Primary Key in version 2.0: I think this does provide a custom lifecycle event for this bulk update case which would partially solve the problem, and it handles joined inheritance updates. But it does not handle relationships either
Batch writes: I can use a session no autoflush block, setattr in a loop for batch size X and commit each batch. But this would still issue write queries one by one, I am not sure there is much performance gain from it

Are there any other options that I am missing? How is this case usually handled?
I am looking into batch updating a field of a list of around 10K objects each time in this scenario
Thanks!
